# Does GitHub notify users when someone downloads the ZIP of a public repo of theirs?

Tags: github

Is there any way for GitHub to notify a person, or track when the .zip file from a plugin repo is downloaded from GitHub?

The ZIP that I am referring to is that which is available when viewing a public repository page on GitHub's website.

Answer (score 6):

There are no ways to do it because GitHub delivers only two kinds of notifications:

- Participating:

  - Someone mentions you or a team you're a member of
  - You are assigned to an issue or pull request
  - Someone makes a comment in a conversation you're subscribed to
- Watching

  - Opened issues and their comments
  - Opened pull requests and their comments
  - Comments on any commits
  - Published releases

Answer (score 2):

Although it will not send a notification, you will be able to see if your repo has been cloned by visiting `/user-name/repo-name/graphs/traffic`. However, you will not be able to identify the user.

Also, downloading a repo using the 'Download Zip' button will not increase the clones/unique clones count.

Comment: thanks @Isopach

Answer (score 1):

The code from any repository can be/will be downloaded without the owner getting notified.

Also, this downloading is similar to using `git clone` which will also not send a notification.